# Balloon Sort C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I am researching about the Balloon Sort because it was one of my assignments, but the Google give me one Balloon Sort link sample only and the rest was Bubble Sort. 
I compiled the code in Dev C++ and said that it has some error...

Here's [a link] (http://www.codemiles.com/c-examples/balloon-sort-algorithm-c-implementation-code-sorting-array-t10823.html) ! That Google gave me...
here is the code...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void balloon()
{ int num, N[10], x, y, z,temp;
clrscr();
cout<<"How many number would you like to sort? ";
cin>>num;
cout<<"Input the "<<num<<" numbers:"<<endl;
for(x=0;x<num;x++)
cin>>N[x];
for(x=0;x<num;x++)
{
for(y=0;y<num-x;y++)
{ if(N[x] > N[x+y])
{ temp=N[x];
N[x] =N[x+y];
N[x+y]=temp;
}
}
cout<<"pass "<<x+1<<"] ";
for(z=0;z<num;z++)
{
cout<<setw(5)<<N[z];
}
cout<<endl;
}
}
```

[Error Picture Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hChFY.png)

Can you help me how to code the Balloon Sort in C++ with some explanations... Thanks in advance!

Comment: wait.. I will edit the post... I just need to know how to input a program here at stackoverflow...

Comment: You are missing two include statements. do a websearch tor the two functions the compiler can't find and you should find documentation pages  that tell you what headers you need to add.

Comment: The code you posted is just a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). The term "balloon sort" is not very common. Of the very few references to it I've seen, some say that it's similar to bubble sort, and some say it's similar to insertion sort. But the few code samples I've seen show it to be a simple selection sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will have some error because the compiler will search the `int main()` so change the void balloon, and remove the `clrsrc();`

Since you used the `setw()`, you must use the `#include <iomanip>`

The header  is part of the Input/output library of the C++ Standard Library. It defines the manipulator functions `resetiosflags()`, `setiosflags()`, `setbase()`, `setfill()`, `setprecision()`, and `setw()`. These functions may be conveniently used by C++ programs to affect the state of iostream objects.

And lastly you must make the `cout<<setw(5)<<N[z];` into `cout<<std::setw(5)<<N[z];`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ int num, N[10], x, y, z,temp;

cout<<"How many number would you like to sort? ";
cin>>num;
cout<<"Input the "<<num<<" numbers:"<<endl;
for(x=0;x<num;x++)
cin>>N[x];
for(x=0;x<num;x++)
{
for(y=0;y<num-x;y++)
{ if(N[x] > N[x+y])
{ temp=N[x];
N[x] =N[x+y];
N[x+y]=temp;
}
}
cout<<"pass "<<x+1<<"] ";
for(z=0;z<num;z++)
{
cout<<std::setw(5)<<N[z];
}
cout<<endl;
}
}
```

and if you run it... here is my sample output

```
How many number would you like to sort? 5
Input the 5 numbers:
8
2
4
9
0
pass 1]     0    8    4    9    2
pass 2]     0    2    8    9    4
pass 3]     0    2    4    9    8
pass 4]     0    2    4    8    9
pass 5]     0    2    4    8    9

--------------------------------
Process exited after 8.305 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Hope this works on your assignment! Good Luck!